# Yield return a bunch of elements

Tags: c#, yield-return

I have a method that returns a list of `MyClass`. Within that method I split a list of `MyClass` into smaller chunks of let´s say 500 elements. Now I wonder if this is possible together with a `yield`-statement. Currently I have this code. However I´m curious if there is a way to yield return the whole bunch without this messy second inner loop.

```
IEnumerable<MyClass> DoSomething() 
{
    List<MyClass> myList = ...
    foreach(var chunk in myList.Chunk(500))  // split the list in smaller lists
    {
        foreach(MyClass m in chunk) yield return m;
    }
}
```

Of course this works, but I wonder if I can also use the `yield` to return the whole bunch deferredly.

Comment: What does `Chunk` do?

Comment: it splits the list into a list of lists

Comment: Can you share the implementation?

Comment: @TrevorPilley Sure, see on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/419019/split-list-into-sublists-with-linq/20953521#20953521

Comment: The duplicate is what I already feared: it is not possible to do so. Either return a list of lists as suggested by Sean or iterate the elements of every bunch and yield it back.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `Chunk` returns some sort of `List<>` you could do:

```
IEnumerable<IList<MyClass>> DoSomething() 
{
    List<MyClass> myList = ...
    foreach(var chunk in myList.Chunk(500))  // split the list in smaller lists
    {
        yield return chunk;
    }
}
```